# My Xbox One will not update to update Aquatic. What do I do?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I open my Minecraft Xbox One it shows “Update to Latest version of Minecraft”. After I click it takes me to the shop and tells me to buy it again.

Is that how it is supposed to work?

I have tried resetting the Xbox and changing the location.

Comment: Sounds like this is something you should contact Microsoft support for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already tried standard procedures like restarting it, I recommend you set your location to you real one, and then make sure you are signed in with the account that owns the licence to Minecraft (this is the account you first got it with). Then try updating again.

If that doesn’t work, you should reach out to Xbox support. They have live chat, which is convenient.